# Read php file with content-type xml

Tags: php, xml

I have a php file where I set the header to `header ("content-type: text/xml");`.
When I try to read the file with `simplexml_load_file()` it returns `false.
But if I set the extension to xml, the file will read correctly.

I use php 5.1.6. With version > 5.3 all works fine. Is this a bug in version 5.1.6. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "read the file" ? Are you fetching it via HTTP ?

Comment: use simplexml_load_file to access to the file.
this is the code

$xml=simplexml_load_file('xml/news.php');
$xml=$xml->children();

p.s: the file exists :)

Answer (score 2):

Try get it as file and than load as string:

```
$str = file_get_contents($file);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
```

Comment: i tried to use the string and the xml was read correctly. The problem is only with php extension. Also flash can't read the file.

Answer (score 0):

`simple_xml_load_file('yourfile.php')` will do a file-based open/read, and you'll be loading raw PHP code directly into simplexml. `simple_xml_load_file('http://example.com/yourfile.php')` will do a full-blown HTTP request and cause yourfile.php to be executed, at which point it should output the xml header and output xml text.